# I really need help with Delphi... text files and arrays with sorting?

Tags: delphi

I have read a text file (of names) into an array and I need how to sort those names into alphabetical order and display that in a rich edit?

Please give me the code from this point onwards:

readln(myfile,arr[i]);

'myfile' is the text file and 'arr' is the array of string.
Also, I have declared 'i' as an integer even though it is a array of string. Is that OK?

Comment: Homework assignment?

Comment: The replies about using TStringList are correct.  As for your question about declaring **i** as an integer even though the array is a string type, yes, that's the right thing to do.  **i** doesn't refer to an element of the array, it's the *index* of the array, and arrays are always indexed by integer values.  (Some objects have indexed properties that can be indexed by other data types, such as strings, but ordinary arrays are always indexed by integers.)

Answer (score 7):

Use a TStringList instead of a array and set the Sort property to true.

```
var
  sortlist : TStringList;            // Define our string list variable
begin
  // Define a string list object, and point our variable at it
  sortlist := TStringList.Create;
  try
    // Now add some names to our list
    sortlist.Sorted := True;

    // And now find Brian's age
    sortlist.LoadFromFile(myfile);

    // Do something.
  finally    
    // Free up the list object
    sortlist.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: names.free should be sortlist.free, and you should have a try..finally to protect the object.

Comment: This assumes that the names are the ONLY contents in the file, which may or may not be a correct assumption.

Answer (score 3):

Use a StringList and then it's easy. StringList can also sort automatically.
See an example here (scroll all the way down):
http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Files

Answer (score 2):

Sorry.  I couldn't help it...

```
program BubblesortTextFile;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

const
  MAX = 100;
  FILE_NAME = 'C:\Text.txt';

type
  TMyRange = 0..MAX;

var
  i,j,top: TMyRange;
  a: Array[TMyRange] of String;
  f: TextFile;
  tmp: String;
begin
  //Init
  i := 0;

  //Read all items from file
  Assign(f, FILE_NAME);
  Reset(f);

  while not Eof(f) do
  begin
    ReadLn(f, a[i]);
    Inc(i);
  end;
  Close(f);
  top := i-1;

  //Bubble sort  (Never use this in real life...)
  for i := Low(TMyRange) to top-1 do
    for j := i+1 to top do
      if a[j] < a[i]
      then begin
        tmp  := a[i];
        a[i] := a[j];
        a[j] := tmp;
      end;

  //Print the array
  for i := 0 to top do
   WriteLn(a[i]);

  //Wait for user
  ReadLn;
end.
```

If you're a newbie: [Welcome, and good luck with Delphi.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39647/whats-the-best-delphi-book-for-a-newbie)
If you're working on a serious project: [Get help...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56222/learning-delphi)